# How to select random option from radio buttons in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, radio-button

We have to select any one radio button option per user in jmeter. How can one achieve the same using jmeter considering the radio button options are: ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The easiest option is using [HTML Link Parser](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser), check out [Poll Example](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#poll_example) - it should be exactly what you're looking for
2. Another option is to extract the values into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) so you will get the following variables defined:

   ```
   foo_1=ONE
   foo_2=TWO
   foo_3=THREE
   foo_4=FOUR
   foo_matchNr=4
   ```

   [image]

   In this case you can use [__V() and __Random() functions combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) in order to generate a random value like:

   ```
   ${__V(foo_${__Random(1,${foo_matchNr},)},)}
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]

Comment: considering the first one, what if I have to use the same value again in further actions? how can I save it in a variable?

Comment: For the HTML Link Parser saving the current value into a variable is not really possible

Comment: I see, what requient we have is, we have 4 radio buttons, 1 user will select any option and same selected option will be used in other actions. any idea how to achieve ths?